# xtext how to tolerate parsing error?

Tags: antlr, xtext

I am write an SQL-like language. Assume the correct syntax is

```
USE foo;
SELECT * FROM bar;
```

but I type it to

```
US foo;
SELECT * FROM bar;
```

Default behavior is Antlr will stop parsing and I lost syntax hightlighting and outline view.
The error message is `Missing EOF at 'US'`. I rebind the IParser to my custom parser in RuntimeModule

```
@Override
public Class<? extends org.eclipse.xtext.parser.IParser> bindIParser() {
    return CustomCqlParser.class;
}
```

Override the `createParser` method in `Parser`

```
@Override
protected InternalCqlParser createParser(XtextTokenStream stream) {
    return new CustomInternalCqlParser(stream, getGrammarAccess());
}
```

and override the method handle this part `recoverFromMismatchedToken` to consume all tokens till semicolon

```
@Override
protected Object recoverFromMismatchedToken(IntStream input, int ttype, BitSet follow) throws RecognitionException {
    Object out = super.recoverFromMismatchedToken(input, ttype, follow);

    if (out == null) {

        beginResync();
        consumeUntil(input, RULE_T_SEMICOLON);
        input.consume();
        endResync();

        Object matchedSymbol = getCurrentInputSymbol(input);
        System.out.println(matchedSymbol);
        return matchedSymbol;
    }
    return out;
}
```

after this `matchedSymbol` is `SELECT`, but the syntax highlight is still gone and antlr stop parsing. How could I achieve my goal?

============ edit ==================================

I copy `super.recoverFromMismatchToken` to my custom class and add this in from of original source code.

```
if (ttype != EOF) {
    beginResync();
    consumeUntil(input, RULE_T_SEMICOLON);
    input.consume();
    endResync();

    Object matchedSymbol = getCurrentInputSymbol(input);
    input.consume(); // move past ttype token as if all were ok
    return matchedSymbol;
}
```

If the token error happens not in the beginning and not `no viable alternative` exception, this will keep syntax highlighting going. But it will still consider it's still using the same parsing rules, not start a new one. Besides, if I typed the wrong token in the beginning, it the expected token would be `EOF`. Which will make my "consume all tokens until semicolon" failed as well.

======================== edit ========================================

tracing `InternalCqlParser.java`, I found out if the typo happened in the first keyword of statements, it will it get an `ID` and return. I add a code snippet after that

```
if (LA1_0 == RULE_IDENT) {
    beginResync();
    consumeUntil(input, RULE_T_SEMICOLON);
    input.consume();
    endResync();
    continue;
}
```

Parsing does continue and syntax highlight remain after the error statement. However the error line won't have any error marker and I lost content assist **after that line**. The class to trigger content assist is `Statement`  but it won't work anymore.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about Cassandra CQL - Are you trying to make the parser actually accept something like "US mykeyspace ;" as a valid USE statement or are you just trying to improve the error message so it doesn't talk about EOF and want to reject the statement in the end?

Comment: Hi I no longer work on this project. At that time I want to keep syntax highlight and other IDE features available, but with an error marker under the wrong statement. In the original situation, if I made a single character typo, whole text editing area will become gray, due to failed parsing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not well supported in general by lexer-based parsers like those generated by Antlr/Xtext, because the lexer has to decide which token to produce without knowing about the parser rules the tokens might be matched by.

In any case, I would not recommend trying to solve this at the Antlr level because you will have to do a lot of customizing in the Xtext tooling.

If possible, I'd recommend thinking about alternative solutions that don't involve the grammar at all:

- If you want better syntax error messages, you can [customize](http://blog.dietmar-stoll.de/2012/07/custom-syntax-error-messages-with-quick.html) them.
- If your use case is supporting the user while typing, a custom [Auto Edit Strategy Provider](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.9/org/eclipse/xtext/ui/editor/autoedit/DefaultAutoEditStrategyProvider.html) may be right.
- If you want to support the user fix errors in existing queries, [Quick Fixes](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/310_eclipse_support.html#quick-fixes) may be the way to go (which can be combined with syntax error messages, cf. the link above).

Only if neither of these is an option, and you really want to **allow** this kind of mistyped syntax, you should try to fix it at the grammar level. 
As I suppose you are talking about a grammar for Cassandra's CQL, I guess there is more than one type of statement (e.g. select, insert, etc.), so hacks involving identifiers interpreted as keywords don't qualify due to grammar ambiguity (apart from their ugliness ;-) ). 
So I guess you have to list all words you are willing to accept as a replacement. 
In this case, I'd suggest creating a [Data Type Rule](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html#datatype-rules) for the mistyped variants of each keyword and another Data Type Rule for identifiers including the mistyped variants, because I guess you don't want to forbid "US" as an identifier.
E.g.:

```
Use:
  ('USE' | MistypedUseKeyword) keyspaceName=Identifier ';';

CreateTable: 

MistypedUseKeyword:
  'US' | 'USW' | 'USEE';

MistypedCreateKeyword:
  'CREAT' | 'CREATW' | 'CERATE' | 'CRATE';

MistypedTableKeyword:
  'TABL' | 'TALBE' | 'TBLE' | 'TBALE' | 'TABEL';

MistypedKeyword:
  MistypedUseKeyword | MistypedCreateKeyword | MistypedTableKeyword;

Identifier:
  ID | MistypedKeyword;
```